# issue with shifting Kohana 2.4 from root location to make it accessible via a directory?

Tags: url-rewriting, kohana

I have developed a kohana project 2.4 version, with i has been developed by configuring virtual host and we are accessing it using some domain aa.com, now i have to move the project to folder named kohana and make it access via aa.com/kohana. If i access it this way then my url changes, So the css & js file are not included since the src url i have provided like /public/css/ so it's not working, same goes for calling a controller. like il be calling a controller using this format /user/login/. now the url when i click to shows like aa.com/user/login which is not found, in turn it should automatically comes like aa.com/kohana/user/login. Is there any way by changing the htaccess file or hacking routes.php file. ?

I should able to automatically append /kohana/ before the url.

Please suggest me a method how it can be achieved.

Comment: Why do you use a 2.4 version? You should select one of 3.x branches (3.2 is latest).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is!

I've only started after kohana 3.0 but you can just change the rewritebase.

In your .htacces it probably says "rewritebase /"

Change this to your new directory. "rewritebase /kohana/"

If 2.4 has a bootstrap (i'm not sure) somewhere it should say "base_url". You change this the same as the .htaccess. /kohana/.

edit: here's an example:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /kohana/

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```